# Iterating over a 2-Dimensional char-Array

Tags: arrays, exception, iteration

Im having a very strange problem with a certain piece of code:

```
for(int r = 0; r<look[0].length; r++){
for(int cl = 0; cl<look.length; cl++ ){
    placeChar(xI+cl, yI+r, look[cl][r]);  // <-- ArrayIndexoOutOfBoundsException
    }
}
```

I'm assuming that 
    look[cl][r]
is the Problem but... how is this possible in any way?
Because r can never be equal or bigger than look[0].length and same for cl.
and look.length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you should

- change the order of iterators
- use `look[cl].length` instead of `look[0].length`

The code:

```
for(int cl = 0; cl<look.length; cl++ ){
   for(int r = 0; r<look[cl].length; r++){
      placeChar(xI+cl, yI+r, look[cl][r]);  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to reverse the order of your loops:

```
for(int cl = 0; cl<look.length; cl++ ){
for(int r = 0; r<look[cl].length; r++){
    placeChar(xI+cl, yI+r, look[cl][r]);
    }
}
```